# Problema al instalar React.js

Tags: reactjs

**Me sale este error, intento hacer que funcione en VS Code podrían ayudarme…?**

**Instale...**

Node.js

npm install -g npm@latest

npm cache clean –force

npm install -g create-react-ap

**y me sale el siguiente error cuando ingreso el comando:**

*create-react-app prueba*

**tambien me sale el mismo error cuando ingreso el comando:**

*npx create-react-app prueba*

**no se que hará falta o como resolverlo, el Node.js es la versión:**

*v18.2.0*

**y la versión de npm es:**

*8.10.0*

**... este es el error ...**

*Aborting installation.

Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:

Error: spawn UNKNOWN

at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)

at Object.spawn (node:child_process:689:9)

at spawn (C:\Users\shida\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-
app\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24)

at C:\Users\shida\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-
app\createReactApp.js:383:19

at new Promise ()

at install (C:\Users\shida\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-
app\createReactApp.js:334:10)

at C:\Users\shida\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-
app\createReactApp.js:461:16

at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {

errno: -4094,

code: ‘UNKNOWN’,

syscall: ‘spawn’

}*

Deleting generated file… package.json

Deleting prueba/ from C:\Users\shida\PRUEBA
Done.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que pudiera ser un problema de caché:

Prueba a ejecutar en consola:

```
npm cache verify
npm cache clean --force
```

Si aun así nada yo probaría a instalar nodejs de nuevo (https://nodejs.org/es/)

Comment: Muchas gracias David Fernández Flores por tan rápida respuesta, pero ya vi que era

Answer (score 0):

Ya vi que era, el antivirus, lo desinstale y cuando se instalo de nuevo el Node.js empezó a instalarse desde PowerShell un montón de complementos, luego en visual studio code todo salió calidad...

Es decir...

1- desinstalan el antivirus

2- desinstalen el Node.js

3- Borran en users\user\roaming borran la carpeta npm y la carpeta npm cache...

4- En local tambien borran la carpeta npm que esta en la siguiente url del disco users\user\local

5- instalan todo de nuevo...